# how can i access objects stored in a list

Tags: r

I'd like to get the content of an variable which I have stored in al list

VB1[i] so I just get the Name back like 'Ro' and not the content of the variable Ro.

Hot can i do that?

```
Mailout <- data.frame(Way = character(0), MA = character(0), Jahr = 
numeric(0),Anzahl = numeric(0), stringsAsFactors=F)
VB1 <- c("Ro","Ha","Sch","Ch")
InfoNr <- 9175
for(i in 1:length(VB1))
{
  assign(paste(VB1[i],sep=""),length(list.files(path = 
paste0("H:\\KD_AKTEN\\",InfoNr,"\\Mail\\"), 
 pattern = glob2rx(paste0("^2017*out*",VB1[i],"*")), ignore.case = TRUE)))

Mailout[nrow(Mailout)+1,] <-c("out",VB1[i],"2017",VB1[i])

}
Mailout
```

Thanks
Olaf

Comment: Please create a *reproducible* and *short* example and specify the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get(VB1[i])` to transform a string into an `R` object.